# Way to script Local Intranet settings?

Tags: windows, security

There's a dialog in the "Internet Options" control panel applet if you go to the Security Tab, highlight "Local Intranet" and press "Sites" that looks something like

```
[X] Automatically detect intranet network
    [ ] Include all local (intranet) sites not listed in other areas
    [ ] Include all sites that bypass the proxy server
    [ ] Include all network paths (UNCs)
```

I'd like to script these settings using PowerShell (or a batch file for that matter). I can't seem to find any documentation on doing that though. I found where they are persisted to the registry, but just changing the registry settings doesn't seem to work so I'm assuming there's some additional work to be done and a more official API for this.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

The preferred way to do this is via GPO.

For Example:

Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel - Security Page, right-click Intranet Sites: `Include all local (intranet) sites listed in other areas` and select Enable.

Comment: Is there a way to apply a GPO via a script and not as part of a domain login? I really need this as part of a script and for machines that are not domain joined.

Comment: Yep. Look into [Security Templates](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/misc_network_security/Understanding-Windows-Security-Templates.html.) You should be able to build a template of your desired local group policy and then apply to your non-domain joined machines.

Comment: There aren't any default templates installed in Win8, so it may take me awhile to get it working. It's just setting the registry though so I'm not sure it'll work either.